# numpy split ndarray based on indices

Tags: python, numpy

For a data set, x, of dimensions (n, m):

```
n = 50
m = 100
x = np.random.random((n,m))
```

I would like to split it into y subsets, so that for 10 subsets it would be based on the indices:

```
index_1 = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
index_2 = [1, 11, 21, 31, 41]
...
index_9 = [8, 18, 28, 38, 48]
index_10 = [9, 19, 29, 39, 49]
```

I know that `np.array_split()` or `np.split()` can be used to subset based on the wanted number of subsets, and i would like a similar output (list of np.ndarrays)

Comment: `[x[i::10] for i in range(10)]`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this as a reference and modify to your needs.

```
import numpy as np
n = 50
m = 100
mylist = np.random.randint(n, size=m)
for i in range(0, len(mylist), 5):
    print(mylist[i:i+5])
```